# Laravel get value of Select from Controller (It is just returning 0 for me)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have run into a roadblock with getting the value of the Select.

Please have a look at my form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('action' => 'MasterController@datamaker')) !!}

{!! Form::select('Area', array('Science', 'Arts',)); !!}

{!! Form::input('date', 'Year') !!}

{!! Form::submit('Add') !!}
```

Here is my (simplified) method in the controller:

```
public function datamaker() {

    $input = Request::all();

    $Database = new Database;

    $Database -> Area = Request::get('Area');
    $Database -> Year = $input['Year'];

    $Database -> save();

    return (Request::get('Area'));  <----- This is returning "0" instead of the values declared in the form

}
```

I have checked other sources and the solutions they have provided have not worked. Whatever I have tried, it always just returns "0" instead of the values declared in the form.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you dump the `$input` array?

Comment: OK, this is what I get: {"_token":"XpUONDKReedDHq9gsFcDmqWvyQVYtB50yJ5JyxCC","Area":"0","Year":""} when I run the following: return($input); "Area" realy returns "0". Maybe it is my form?

Comment: Insert the HTML code that is generated by Laravel.

Comment: Ok, one moment please. Haven't got much experience with laravel so please bear with me. Thanks!

Comment: You just need to open the source code of the form page (usually CTRL+U) and paste in the results here.

Comment: <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/library-software/public/dataadd" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="XpUONDKReedDHq9gsFcDmqWvyQVYtB50yJ5JyxCC">
                <p>Area</p>
                <!--<input name="Area" type="text">-->
                <select name="Area"><option value="0">Science</option><option value="1">Arts</option></select>
                <p>Year</p>
                <input name="Year" type="date">
                <input type="submit" value="Add"> (I removed some stuff because it was too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: Now looking at it, maybe what I should be referencing is the "Text" and not the "Value"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `0` instead of `Science` is that Form component, when generating a `select`, uses array keys as values of available options and array values as string that is displayed in the select. You don't provide array keys, so the keys are `0` for `Science` and `1` for `Arts`.

If you want to get `Science/Arts` as the value from `Request::get('Area')` you need to pass an array to `Form::select()` where values and keys are the same strings, e.g.

```
Form::select('Area', ['Science' => 'Science', 'Arts' => 'Arts']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try this. And then let you know how it went.

Comment: This worked. But it brings to attention how much more reading I have to do in Laravel. I could have pulled this off easy using just regular php, but it took me 2 hours of googling to get here. But hey, thanks for the answer. You can have my thumbs up.